# Modernizer Polyfill vs Prefixed CSS3

Tags: javascript, performance, css, modernizr, polyfills

I am using a polyfill so that box-sizing should work with all JS enabled browsers to prevent the layout problems which looks like this:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
//extend modernizer
Modernizr.addTest("boxsizing", function() {
    return Modernizr.testAllProps("boxSizing") && (document.documentMode === undefined || document.documentMode > 7);
    });
$(function(){
    if( !($('html').hasClass('boxsizing')) ){
        $('.boxSized, .boxSized *').each(function(){
            var fullW = $(this).outerWidth(),
                actualW = $(this).width(),
                wDiff = fullW - actualW,
                newW = actualW - wDiff;

            $(this).css('width',newW);
        });
    }
});

</script>
```

However looking at this code when ever a browser doesn't have `box-sizing:` enabled it will resort to the use of this short polyfill which I don't think should impact site performance to much ?

My problem is as follows at the moment I am using prefixed elements e.g.

```
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
```

I am wondering if the prefixed elements are now redundant as the polyfill overrides them or if there is still benefit to having them etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modernizr will include those prefixed styles in its detection, so yes, you should keep them.

If you drop them, then your site will break because browsers which require a prefix will be detected by Modernizr as supporting the feature and thus and won't run the javascript code, so you won't have the style at all for those browsers.

The Javascript code will only be used by IE7<sup>*</sup> or earlier, where the `box-sizing` style is not supported at all.

(<sup>*</sup> ...or other *really* old browsers like Opera 9 or Firefox 1, but realistically no-one is using those)

Comment: So you don't see the need to add a conditional statement to the polyfill for IE as it will only be picked up when needed (browser doesn't support any box-szing?) and shouldn't impact site performance greatly when the browser does support Box-sizing.

Comment: Correct. For browsers that support `box-sizing`, the perfomance impact will be minimal. It will have to download Modernizr (but you're doing that anyway, right?), and it will have to do the Modernizr test, but that's pretty lightweight, so not much impact. You could make it zero impact on other browsers by using conditional comments instead of the modernizr test, but the difference really won't be that much.

Comment: indeed Modernizer is already downloaded when you say for browsers that support box-sizing does this include safari and firefox etc using prefixed styles. What i am trying to get as is this overriding the moz and webkit prefixes and using the JS polyfill as for instance firefox in some cases doesn't support box-sizing tag on its own but obviously supports the prefixed styles so does the JS flag this up as no box-sizing! sorry thats so long winded i started confusing myself

Comment: As stated in the Modernizr documentation: *Modernizr.testAllProps() investigates whether a given style property, **or any of its vendor-prefixed variants**, is recognized.* In other words, your test for `boxSizing` will return `true` for Firefox, even though FF only supports the prefixed version. Which means that the polyfill code will not be run in Firefox. The polyfill will only run in browsers that don't support `boxSizing` at all, like IE7.

Answer (score 0):

the polyfill you using isn't really good for performance.. so you better use this polyfill for [IE 6/7](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill). 
and use this snippet for everything else since box-sizing is supported in every browser as you can see in this [table](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing).

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Webkit browsers chrome/safari */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

NOTE : box-sizing is supported in IE 6 and earlier in quirks mode.

Comment: "box-sizing is supported in IE 6 and earlier in quirks mode." No.